# TextBox2 not Change?

Tags: c#

```
namespace Program001
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBox1.Items.Add("E");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("W");
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "E")
            {
                int hr = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                int Zd = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                int output = hr - Zd;
                if (output <= 0)
                {
                    int Q = output + 24;
                    textBox2.Text = Q.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox2.Text = output.ToString();
                }

            }
            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == "W")
            {
                int hr = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                int Zd = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
                int output = hr + Zd;
                if (output >= 24)
                {
                    int Q = output - 24;
                    textBox2.Text = Q.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    textBox2.Text = output.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know what is your question, but I don't recommend to set `textBox2`'s `Text` in its `TextChanged` event because it will result in an infinite recursion.

Comment: Use the Validating event instead.  Always use TryParse().  Don't forget to subscribe the event handler.